Shibboleth SP deleting Load balancer set Cookie
We have a Load balancer for the application and Shibboleth SP,Azure ADP for authentication.
We use Load balancer cookie persistence for session persistence with timeout set for 10 hrs.
1.Initially when user logs into application with a clear cache, below cookie was in response header with timeout 10 hrs and no issues.
Set-Cookie: X-Oracle-OCI-LB=eb6b8f5ea57e1479d2e04674de09203701c2118b; Max-Age=36000; Path=/
2. If user closes the browser and logs again with in 10 hrs,  cookies are getting deleted and we suspect Shibboleth SP is deleting the cookies.
Below Cookie exists initially within request header when user hits the URL.
X-Oracle-OCI-LB=eb6b8f5ea57e1479d2e04674de09203701c2118b
after that in "POST /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST HTTP/1.1" doesn't have the load balancer cookie any more.
Any idea why the Load balancer cookies are getting deleted by Shibboleth SP and is there any way to prevent the cookies from deleting. ?
I tried playing with CookieProps setting on Shibboleth SP but that didn't resolve preserving the cookies.

CookieProps are only going to apply to the cookie that's specified as the SP's application cookie as defined by cookieName in the <Sessions> element of shibboleth2.xml. See: https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SP3/pages/2065334342/Sessions#Attributes
